# creating  a dynamic "recently opened files" menu

Tags: c#, winforms, menustrip

I want to add a feature to my MenuStrip where I want there to be an option where you can hover over or press the menu option to open **recently opened projects** .

`File---> Recently Opened Projects---> {List of projects.....}`

The same kind of option/menu that exists in Microsoft office products (e.g. word 2007).

I know how to get an array of the file names. I just need to know how to put the array of the names at the Sub MenuStrip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add them dynamically in code:

```
    private void menuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem item = new ToolStripMenuItem();
        item.Text = "your file name";
        item.Click += new EventHandler(yourEventHandler);
        menuItem.DropDownItems.Add(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `ToolStripMenuItem`s in a loop and call `DropDownItems.Add` to add them to your parent menu item.
In the loop, you should add a handler to their `Click` event.

Comment: it sounds complex. i think i wont carry that algorithm, could anyone tell me instead how you can prevent anything to touch your menustrip. some labels are being glued behind my menustrip... i remember i did that through the Forms properties, but i forgot how!!!!